# Does the python sys.path act like Unix PATH?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a local development directory with modules that I'm writing, and a system-wide site-packages directory where these modules will eventually be installed. In the case where I'm modifying an existing module and I want to test it I would like to be sure that the module I'm importing is the one in my local site-packages directory. Reading about the [site](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) module it seems like I can have a file with a `.pth` suffix where each line in that file will be appended to the `sys.path` variable. I've set that up, and I can confirm that my development directory is showing up later in the list, but when I import a module it's importing from the system wide directory.

Simplified Example:

```
$ virtualenv test_sys
$ cd test_sys
$ source bin/activate
$ mkdir site_modules
$ mkdir user_modules
```

In each site_modules and user_modules I've put a directory called `test_module` with the following in the `__init__.py`:

```
import os

print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Now I've added a file called `site_modules.pth` to `test_sys/lib/python2.7/site-packages`:

```
/home/chris/test_sys/site_modules
/home/chris/test_sys/user_modules
```

And I expect that when I import test_module from the python interpreter it would print the `user_modules` directory but it doesn't:

```
>>> import test_module
/home/chris/test_sys/site_modules/test_module/__init__.pyc
>>>
```

Yes, I've ensured that `user_modules` shows up later in `sys.path` than `site_modules`.

How can I ensure that a module that exists in multiple directories in `sys.path` will always be imported from a specific directory?

Comment: Also see [The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in the Python docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `sys.path` does work mostly like the Unix `PATH` environment variable.  Both of them use the first object they find in the path.  So if you want to have `user_modules` override `site_modules`, you have to put it *first*, not *second*:

```
/home/chris/test_sys/user_modules
/home/chris/test_sys/site_modules
```

This is the same as Unix `PATH`

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Which means that *local* packages (ones not installed by the package manager) from `/usr/local` will override system packages in `/usr`.